# In handsontable - convert number to date by function and load refresh more data

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I am using handsontable for creating a CRUD (create read update delete) interface for my databases which now require these two things.

1. Able to create/update/delete `rows/cells which are changed` (and not the whole data set)
2. Able to `load more data` from database (as new records are added) or `refresh changed rows`

-

### Part 1 (Solved) - http://jsfiddle.net/p7KwM/

So I added a field name `modified as timestamp (INT)` to database so that data can be refreshed at user side by checking this modified field, and it is INT so that TZ value can be added as per user. See here http://demo.mgvz.com/.twilio/loader.pl and now `I am stuck at that I want to modify this INT to add TZ value and to covert it to date-time format within handsontable`. (Can't do it server side) If it can be modified by way of function within handsontable, else the only option is to modify it before giving it to handsontable.

### Part 2 (any help appreciated)

Second, I have to `add rows which are created on server` and `update rows which are changed on server`, without effecting other unchanged rows, (a user might be editing other rows), and to maintain sorting while adding the rows.

Can anyone guide me about it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update data, have a look at `setDataAtCell` method:

```
setDataAtCell (row: Number, col: Number, value: Mixed, source: String (Optional))
```

To add new rows created on server, have a look at the `alter` method:

```
alter ('insert_row', index: Number, amount: Number (Optional), source: String (Optional))
```

You can find more detailed description of those 2 methods [here](https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/wiki/Methods)

So to update something that was changed on server:

```
$container.handsontable('setDataAtCell', rowIndex, colNumber, "New Value");
```

And to add new:

```
var rowIndex = 2; //You will need to determine this to maintain sorting, or set to null to add as last row.
var numberOfRows 1; //Only adding one row at a time
$container.handsontable('alter', 'insert_row', rowIndex, colNumber);
//After row is added you can update the values of each column using setDataAtCell as per above
$container.handsontable('setDataAtCell', rowIndex, 1, "FirstName");
$container.handsontable('setDataAtCell', rowIndex, 2, "LastName");
//One line for each column or have a look at the setDataAtCell method for alternative option
```

You may enocunter issues if the user is for example editing values that need updating, or what happens if you add a row while user is editing?

I hope any of this helps

Comment: Thank you, i will try this `alter`, and also to add multiple rows and keep results sorted. As of now I had turned off sorting ;)